# How do I get the average row count per day of data?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a large table in Teradata that gets new data loaded into it daily. It has a column called `CAL_DT` that is the date that row was loaded into the table. I'd like to write a query that will give me the average row count per day so I can see how much data generally gets loaded in a day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can count the number of rows and divide by the number of days:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct cal_dt)
from t;
```

This gives the average for each day when data was loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could do that in a select.